# laravel 5 built in scaffolding tried to use username instead of email error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I already created a column username and fill it in the users table that was used with the laravel 5 built in login scaffolding and what I'm trying to do is to use username instead of the default email so I tweak the code that I found in laravel\vendor\compiled.php with the following (refer below)

this default code

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, array('email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required'));
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
    return redirect($this->loginPath())->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))->withErrors(array('email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage()));
}
```

to

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, array('email' => 'required', 'password' => 'required'));
    if ($this->auth->attempt(['username' =>  $request->input('email'), 'password' =>  $request->input('password'), $request->has('remember')])) {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
    return redirect($this->loginPath())->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))->withErrors(array('email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage()));
}
```

but it give me an error saying

> QueryException in Connection.php line 620:
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `dodong_users` where `username` = dodong@dodong.com and `0` = 0 limit 1)

any help, suggestion, recommendation, clues, ideas to fix this so that I could login with username instead of email would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
if ($this->auth->attempt(['username' =>  $request->input('email'), 'password' =>  $request->input('password'), $request->has('remember')])) {
```

To this:

```
if ($this->auth->attempt(['username' =>  $request->input('email'), 'password' =>  $request->input('password')], $request->has('remember'))) {
```

Looks like you just put `$request->has('remember')` in the wrong place. It was looking for a column called `0` because you passed the value of `$request->has('remember')` as part of the `attempt()` data.

To use an example from the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#authenticating-users), you were doing this:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, $remember]))
{
    // The user is being remembered...
}
```

When you should have been doing this:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember))
{
    // The user is being remembered...
}
```